# Program 'yarn.exe' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation

Tags: yarn-v2

I'm having an issue after installing Yarn I got this error: "The system cannot find the file specified.
command not found: copy yarn"

After some googling I was instructed to change the environment path in "C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Yarn\bin" in order for it to locate the executable.

However, after I did this I was met with a problem that I have yet to resolve and I've tried several things such as ("Re-installing Yarn, Node.js, delete all Yarn related files, using powershell as admin, removing yarn.ps1.")

I get this error:

> Program 'yarn.exe' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
> yarn
>
> - 
>
> At line:1 char:1
> yarn
>
> - 
>
> CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Whenever I use anything related to Yarn in either Powershell or in Vs code.
Not even Yarn --version works. If anyone has any clue how to resolve this issue I would be very grateful. I've tried everything that I can think of.

("Re-installing Yarn, Node.js, delete all Yarn related files, using powershell as admin.")

I was expecting that it the issue would be resolved and I could focus on solving problem #1 again.